# How to get all points of object in order to then link all of with a line

Tags: python, geometry

So for a project, I would need to be able to export all the points of an low-poly object with in order. What I mean by order is that I have for exemple point #1 that make a line with point #2, #3 and #4. The goal is to be able to trace the model with a or multiple line(s) made by a sequence of those points.

I have tried to used obj files but it didn't work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please define 'in order' . Is that index order? Or some order with respect to the geometry?